# Login should be succesful but does not link to my main menu interface

Tags: android, json

This is my logcat

```
12-08 14:45:21.179: D/request!(6046): starting
12-08 14:45:21.719: D/Login attempt(6046): {"message":"Login successful!","success":1}
```

This is my Login.java

```
public class Login extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener  {

private Button login,register;
private EditText email,password;
// Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.1.14:1234/PMSS/login.php";      
  //JSON element ids from repsonse of php script:
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerlauncher);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userid);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String Username = email.getText().toString();
            String Password = password.getText().toString();
            new AttemptLogin(Username,Password).execute();
        }
    });

    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        // For the main activity, make sure the app icon in the action bar
        // does not behave as a button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    /*case R.id.login:
            new AttemptLogin().execute();
        break;
    case R.id.register:
            Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
            startActivity(i);
        break;
*/
    default:
        break;
    }
}

//AsyncTask is a seperate thread than the thread that runs the GUI
    //Any type of networking should be done with asynctask.
class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    //three methods get called, first preExecture, then do in background, and once        do
    //in back ground is completed, the onPost execture method will be called.
        boolean failure = false;
   String res;
   String Username; 
   String Password;
   int success;
   public AttemptLogin(String Username, String Password) {
            this.Username = Username;
            this.Password = Password;
   }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", Username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", Password));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");
            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                   LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);
            System.out.print("Here");
            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            res = json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            return res;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(int success) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();

            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Login Successful!", res);
                Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, MainMenu.class);
                startActivity(i);
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Log.d("Login Failure!", res);
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

    }
}
}
```

As the logcat said I login succesfully but in my android phone still having the `Attemping Login...`  and it will not go to my MainMenu interface. There is no compilation and runtime errors. I was wonder `Intent i = new Intent(Login.this,MainMenu.class);` and `startActivity(i);` does not work?

Comment: Do you see this  `Log.d("Login Successful!", res)` in log??

Comment: I didnt saw this in logcat

Comment: then onPostExecute is not executed. you return string in doInbackground. So onPostExecute should expect a string as a param. pls check the asynctask docs to know more about it. there is nothing wrong with your intent and startactivity

Comment: So, What should I do? I really need to figure this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return `success` instead of `res` from your `doInBackground`. There is also something wrong with the types (arguments, return) of the various methods in `AsyncTask`. The return type of `doInBackground` should be the same as the argument type of `onPostExecute`.

Change your code like this:

```
class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, Integer> {
    ...
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... args) {
        ...
        return success;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer success) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I try change the `return res` to `return succees` but the return type is not int.. What should I do?

Comment: Change the return type as well. I'd suggest `Integer`.

Comment: I change the return type to int as in `protected int doInBackground(String... args)` but the error said `The return type is incompatible with AsyncTask<String,String,String>.doInBackground(String[])` Eclipse suggest me change back to String

Comment: Thanks for the update, even though I success login and move to my next interface, but the 2 main problems come, The first problem is  even i write wrong password or userid it also said Login succesfully and move to main menu which is wrongly implemented. The second problem is if i fill nothing for userid and password and click login button it will lead me to forced close apps